# Как правильно задать права на сервере

Tags: веб-сервер

Как должны быть настроены права, чтобы сайт мог нормально записать  данные в свои конфиги в document_root.

Стоит nginx + php-fpm. Nginx работает от пользователя www-data.

Все файлы сайта принадлежат пользователю rayzor и той же группе, что логично.

Данный пользователь зайдёт по ssh и склонирует репозиторий от своего имени.

Что же после и перед каждого git pull менять владельца и права? Или поставить на файлы права 777? Это тоже неправильно. Или поставить чтобы nginx Работал от пользователя rayzor?

Какой вариант нормальный? Так сказать, чтобы не было стыдно перед покемонами

Comment: господи, какой кошмар. Зачем заходить по фтп и как вы по фтп "клонируете репозиторий"?

Comment: ок, не дописал букву...sftp, а клонирую по ssh.

Comment: вы все равно не описали проблему. У вас есть git-репозиторий и какой-то nginx, как они между собой пересекаются? По идее, ваш git не должен быть доступен через nginx/apache/и т.д., вы стучитесь к нему по ssh, клонируете и все.  Вы можете обновить и уточнить ваш вопрос?

Comment: причём тут git?
Мы от рута поставили и настроили сервер, настроили виртуальный хост. Потом создали пользователя, залогинились под ним и закачали на сервер сайт, который отдаётся сервером. Естественно, у файлов закаченных пользователем владелец и группа данный пользователь, да и чтобы править файлы пользователю - нужны именно такие права, соответ. сам сайт правит эти файлы не может. Права на файлы выглядят так: rw-rw-r. Как сделать чтобы и пользователь писал в файлы и nginx который работает от пользователя www-data.

Comment: Суть в том, что у файла и пользователь и группа одна и таже, а редактировать файл нужно двум пользователям.